# Do I own the code in a private Github Repository?

Tags: github

I am wondering, whether I own the code in my private Github repository. Does github have the right to publish the code or parts of the code?

Thanks a lot!

Konrad

Comment: Check out those clear answers from Stackexchange: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2907/does-the-owner-of-the-github-repository-own-the-copyright-to-the-code

Comment: Yeah. There it is. Thanks